# With an initial commit, is "add ." and "add *" synonymous?

Tags: git

Will `git add .` and `git add *` accomplish exactly the same things?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No it will not.

`*` is a glob pattern, and will not match files which begin with a `.`

For example, let this be the current directory and I have 2 new files to add `foo` and `.bar`

```
$ ls -l

-rw-r--r-- 1 me users     0 Mar  7 19:31 foo
-rw-r--r-- 1 me users     0 Mar  7 19:31 .bar
```

When I run `git add *`:

```
$ git add *

$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   foo
#
# Untracked files:
#   (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)
#
#   .bar
```

Instead if I run `git add .`

```
$ git add .

$ git status
# On branch master
# Changes to be committed:
#   (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)
#
#   new file:   .bar
#   new file:   foo
#
```

BTW using `git add * .*` would produce **incorrect results**, if you want to add only all the files under a particular directory you're in.

Let us consider this case, I've 6 new files:

```
foo
.bar
mydir/abc
mydir/.def
mydir2/newfile1
mydir2/newfile2
```

If I'm in `mydir` and run `git add .` git adds only the following files:

```
mydir/abc
mydir/.def
```

Instead if you run the command `git add * .*`, git adds the files in `mydir` in addition to any changes present one directory level above since `.*` glob pattern also matches `../`. In other words, the following files will be added:

```
foo
.bar
mydir/abc
mydir/.def
mydir2/newfile1
mydir2/newfile2
```

Comment: Then you can do `git add * .*`.  :)

Comment: is it fine to run `git add .` after the fact when you've already created the repository?

Comment: Yes `git add .` can be run as many times whenever you want to add any new files and existing files under `version control`. If the files do not have any changes, `git` is not going to add them. If you want to pick out files that you want to add specify file names explicitly or use a `glob` pattern that matches only those files.

Comment: @JohnZwinck - I've added why your command is totally incorrect and can produce unintended behavior.

Comment: @JohnZwinck i have found that there a fine, almost indistinguishable line, between rudeness and fact-checking in the world of code. goes with the territory.

Comment: Sure, that's why I'm still smiling.  At least I gave Tuxdude a nice lay-up to demonstrate how the commands differ!

Comment: @JohnZwinck - Didn't meant to be rude, just wanted to make sure that people reading the answer do not get confused by the comment with good number of upvotes. Honestly, I myself have tried `.*` approach in a few cases where it worked, until I realized the flaw.

Answer (score 2):

In a lot of cases they'll be the same, but not always.  In the second case, the `*` is expanded by the shell using normal globbing rules, so no files in the current directory starting with a `.` will get added, for example.

Comment: is it fine to run git add . after the fact when you've already created the repository?